# std::for_each() and calling constructors/destructors

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have problems using `for_each()` and calling constructors/destructors on each element.

For reference, `mBegin` points to the start of the array, `mEnd` beyond the last element, `mCapacity` points to the end of allocated memory.

```
template <typename T>
void IDMapTree<T>::Grow()
{
    const size_t prevSize = mCapacity - mBegin;
    const size_t newSize = prevSize != 0 ? static_cast<size_t>(1.5f * prevSize) : 1;
    T* newBuffer = static_cast<T*>(mAllocator.Allocate(newSize));

    // initialize new buffer elements with copy constructor using old elements
    uint32_t itemIndex = 0;
    std::for_each(newBuffer, newBuffer + prevSize, [&](T& item) { item.T(*(mBegin + itemIndex++)); });
    // destruct all old elements
    std::for_each(mBegin, mEnd, [](T& item) { item.~T(); });


    // ...
}
```

This segment compiles fine:

```
std::for_each(mBegin, mEnd, [](T& item) { item.~T(); });
```

But this dosn't:

```
std::for_each(newBuffer, newBuffer + prevSize, [&](T& item) { item.T(*(mBegin + itemIndex++)); });
```

Not even if I use the default constructor like this:

```
std::for_each(newBuffer, newBuffer + prevSize, [](T& item) { item.T(); });
```

The compiler (VS2013) says the following:

```
error C2039: '__this' : is not a member of 'JonsEngine::SceneNode'
error C2039: 'T' : is not a member of 'JonsEngine::SceneNode'
```

In this case, `T` is of type `JonsEngine::SceneNode`.

What is the issue here? Why dosn't `T()` resolve to `SceneNode()`? Why does the destructor work but not the constructor?

Comment: You are trying to call the constructor of an already existing object? o.0

Comment: Why are you calling destructor explicitely? Have you constructed the elements using placement new?

Comment: Just use `std::vector` as storage.

Comment: Using placement new yes and why can't you use for_each for this purpose  of calling the destructor?

Comment: I cant just use vector for reasons outside of the scope of this question. If the statement is wrong, please elaborate?

Comment: This is really ugly. There could be something wrong with your approach that is outside of the scope of your code snippet. I think you are trying to write C in C++. Could you describe the context of the problem briefly?

Comment: It's just a container that needs to use custom memory allocators. I can't build on other containers due to how its elements will be handled. What is the issue? It isn't clear to me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`std::uninitialized_copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_copy) for this.

Answer (score 0):

do it like the stl does it - pass the uninitialized memory chunk as `void* ptr` and then

`::operator new(ptr) T(item)`

`item` should be passed as const reference. (or better - move)

```
char* newBuffer = static_cast<char*>(mAllocator.Allocate(newSize));
if (newSize % sizeof(T) != 0){
  throw std::runtime_error("memory is not alligned");
}
for (size_t i = 0; i< newSize; i += sizeof(T)){
   ::operator new((void*)ptr) T(item)
}
```

you should also *move* the objects instead of copy and deleting the old ones.
this will also free you from the need to destruct the old objects.

Edit:
I don't see why the downvote when this is the correct way to call any constructor on a pre-allocated memory block. this is the MSVC++ `Allocator::construct` function which does the same thing

```
void construct(_Ty *_Ptr, const _Ty& _Val)
    {   // construct object at _Ptr with value _Val
    ::new ((void *)_Ptr) _Ty(_Val);
    }
```

want to downvote MSVC++ reputation as well?

Comment: he's clearly doing some sort of (weird) allocator. think as if this block of code was in `allocator::construct` , suddenly we wouldn't be so negative about it.

Comment: also, I don't see how can you judge what is considered a good solution when you don't even know what problem the OP is trying to solve

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use placement new.

btw your use of destructors is fine:

```
// destruct all old elements
std::for_each(mBegin, mEnd, [](T& item) { item.~T(); });
```

The expression `item.~T();` is the right way to explicitly call a destructor.

*You cannot call constructors this way.*

So, placement new could be the way to go:

```
std::for_each(newBuffer, newBuffer + prevSize, [](T& item) { new (&item) T(); });
```

btw when using lambdas within a member function you might need to pass `this` into the capture list.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the destructor work but not the constructor?

Because destructor belongt to instance and constructot belongs to type.

You can't call the constuctor having the instance, you have to call it using name of the type. Anyway, you are doing something strange.